# Split one list into many different lists based on values in file

Tags: python, list, data-processing

I have a file that looks like

```
15.000000,4.934615,33.537294,0.000000,-21.361950,-1.615271,-0.992763
15.000000,9.869230,34.425931,0.000000,-21.434786,-1.612010,-0.906316
25.000000,0.009869,55.896075,0.009791,-0.001660,-2.851388,-3.211835
25.000000,0.394769,56.965853,0.000000,-18.970081,-2.847448,-2.445059
25.000000,0.592154,56.309530,0.000000,-19.053814,-2.849857,-2.360779
25.000000,0.789538,56.658209,0.000000,-19.113064,-2.848573,-2.300981
25.000000,0.986923,56.302130,0.000000,-19.158900,-2.849884,-2.254598
25.000000,4.934615,56.602144,0.000000,-19.482491,-2.848779,-1.920057
25.000000,9.869230,56.320800,0.000000,-19.612882,-2.849815,-1.775979
25.000000,197.384600,56.557439,0.000000,-19.715587,-2.848943,-1.153281
35.000000,0.789538,79.028859,0.000000,-17.360379,-4.135952,-3.466161
35.000000,0.986923,78.349773,0.000000,-17.424764,-4.138463,-3.401225
35.000000,4.934615,78.161552,0.000000,-17.882104,-4.139163,-2.932865
```

That I am trying to plot using numpy and matplotlib. I am setting up my list like so, using pandas:

```
colnames = ['t','p','simfug','statefug','state_ex_mu','ideal_mu','sim_mu']
data = pandas.read_csv(sys.argv[1], names = colnames)
t = data.t.tolist()
p = data.p.tolist()
simfug = data.simfug.tolist()
```

(Using the first column 't' as an example...)
what I would like to do is create separate lists and group the values of the other variables by their t values, so I can then plot my data as lines based on t as opposed to a scatter plot like what I have [currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk6jR.png).

Thank you very much for your time and any help you may be able to offer!

Comment: Sounds like a job for [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)